# JSON - Unable to serialize JSONObject within Object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have the following class:

```
class A{    
    String abc;
    String def;
    // appropriate getters and setters with JsonProperty Annotation 
}
```

and I call `Jacksons objectMapper.writeValueAsString(A)` which works fine.

Now I need to add another instance member:

```
class A{    
    String abc;
    String def;
    JSONObject newMember; // No, I cannot Stringify it, it needs to be JSONObject
    // appropriate getters and setters with JsonProperty Annotation 
}
```

but when I serialize, I am getting exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

I tried JSONNode but it gave Output as {outerjson:**"**{innerjson}**"**} not {outerjson:{innerjson}}.

Is it possible to use Jackson to achieve the above output, i.e. JSONObject within JSONObject?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the expected output from a given input?

Comment: Why not use the ```ObjectNode``` provided by Jackson?

Answer (score 5):

What about to use `jackson-datatype-json-org`

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsonorg.JsonOrgModule;

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JsonOrgModule());
```

See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-json-org

Comment: Unclear why this has been down-voted, it worked for me and I always prefer to use an existing library than rolling my own solution.

Comment: This should be the anwers : the project has move there 
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-misc/tree/master/json-org

Answer (score 4):

Use `@JsonSerialize` with the attribute and implement a custom serializer.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonObjectSerializer.class)
private JSONObject jsonObject;

public static class JsonObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<JSONObject> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(JSONObject jsonObject, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeRawValue(jsonObject.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you cannot replace the JSONObject on a POJO or a Map, then you can write a [custom serializer](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers). Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonJSONObject {

    public static class MyObject {
        public final String string;
        public final JSONObject object;

        @JsonCreator
        public MyObject(@JsonProperty("string") String string, @JsonProperty("object") JSONObject object) {
            this.string = string;
            this.object = object;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyObject{" +
                    "string='" + string + '\'' +
                    ", object=" + object +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("org.json");
        module.addSerializer(JSONObject.class, new JsonSerializer<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(JSONObject value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
            jgen.writeRawValue(value.toString());
            }
        });
        module.addDeserializer(JSONObject.class, new JsonDeserializer<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public JSONObject deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                Map<String, Object> bean = jp.readValueAs(new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
                return new JSONObject(bean);
            }
        });
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(Collections.singletonMap("key", "value"));
        String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new MyObject("string", object));

        System.out.println("JSON: " + json);
        System.out.println("Object: " + mapper.readValue(json, MyObject.class));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JSON: {
  "string" : "string",
  "object" : {"key":"value"}
}
Object: MyObject{string='string', object={"key":"value"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonNode instead of JSONObject.

```
JsonNode jsonNode = JsonLoader.fromString(YOUR_STRING);
```